INSTEAD OF INSERT ON never gets triggered from continous aggregate (timescale)
I'm trying to make a trigger based on when a continuous aggregate is updated.
I had the trigger working on the source table, but when trying to add it on the aggregate:
CREATE TRIGGER request_insert_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON request_summary
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION notify_request_insert();

I get:
ERROR:  "request_summary" is a view
Views cannot have row-level BEFORE or AFTER triggers

So I changed AFTER INSERT ON to INSTEAD OF INSERT ON (see below), based on the documentation, and then I dont get an error. But my notification never triggers.
Perhaps what I'm trying to do isn't even possible? (but if it is not possible to have triggers on views, why does the trigger creation with AFTER INSERT ON not give an error?)
I've tried using non-real-time aggregation, but the problem remains even then. There are no errors in my logs.
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW request_summary
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT name,
   time_bucket(INTERVAL '5s', time) AS bucket,
   AVG(response_time),
   count(*)
FROM request
GROUP BY name, bucket;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_request_insert()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    payload JSON;
BEGIN
    -- Convert the new row into JSON
    payload := row_to_json(NEW);
    -- Send the notification with the payload
    PERFORM pg_notify('insert_event', payload::text);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER request_insert_trigger
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON request_summary
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION notify_request_insert();


I am a bit confused. You are asking "why does the trigger creation with AFTER INSERT ON not give an error", but the error message you are showing seems to suggest that you got an error alright.

It gave an error with AFTER INSERT ON (which worked on a regular table), but then I changed it to INSTEAD OF INSERT ON and then it gives no error, but also never triggers

I added the AFTER INSERT ON version to the start of my question to make it more clear. I also tried AFTER INSERT ON combined with FOR EACH STATEMENT, but that never triggers either.

Your question still contains the sentence "But then why does the trigger creation with AFTER INSERT ON not give an error?" That is the source of my confusion.

"INSTEAD OF INSERT ON request_summary" does not cause an error. "AFTER INSERT ON" does.
My problem is not the error, but the fact that "INSTEAD OF INSERT ON" does not trigger.

What I meant by "why does it not give an error" is: "If INSTEAD OF INSERT ON is not possible/supported on views, why does it not give an error"? The sentence in bold gives the context :)

Ok, I give up. Perhaps somebody smarter than me can understand that.

Feel free to ignore that sentence completely.

I rephrased it and put it in parenthesis to give it less focus...

I just tried to create an INSTEAD OF trigger on a materialized view and got DETAIL:  This operation is not supported for materialized views.. Perhaps that is something specific for TimescaleDB; perhaps that is not really a materialized view. At any rate, only someone with TimescaleDB might be able to answer this.

You cannot implement such rule because Timescaledb haven't mapped such rule.
Just to be clear, materialized views WITH (timescaledb.continuous) are hypertables and not a regular materialized view.
In this case, you can just use another mechanism like a trigger after insert or using scheduled jobs with a fixed schedule:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE notify_new_candlestick(job_id int, config jsonb)
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
DECLARE
  view_name TEXT := config ->> 'view_name';
  last_row RECORD;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I ORDER BY time_bucket DESC LIMIT 1', view_name)
  INTO last_row;
  PERFORM pg_notify(view_name, row_to_json(last_row)::text);
END
$$;

SELECT add_job('notify_new_candlestick', '10s', config => '{"view_name": "candlestick_10s"}', fixed_schedule => true);
SELECT add_job('notify_new_candlestick', '1m', config => '{"view_name": "candlestick_1m"}', fixed_schedule => true);
SELECT add_job('notify_new_candlestick', '5m', config => '{"view_name": "candlestick_5m"}', fixed_schedule => true);

Check the full example to see it in action: https://github.com/jonatas/sql-snippets/blob/master/caggs_notify2.sql

Makes sense! I’ll try out the suggested solutions!
